# Where should questions be stored for a test engine in Java

Tags: java

I am thinking about developing a Java based test engine.

The problem is where should the questions be stored: in database, file (.doc) or should I write them inside my code?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand your problem. Please give us a hint what you have tried and what is the expected output. And what will be tested.Please answer immediately ;)

Comment: It depends on constraints you have in your project, technology you want to use, use cases, etc... Is it a web app, is it a standalone single user app, etc etc... Will you add questions, will you change and update them often... So, please specify your question better. Immediately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of project you are doing.

I wouldn’t recommend to have the question in the code, as it can get complicated and messy with if there is a large amount of questions.

File work good, but wouldn’t recommend doc format, a plain “.txt” format is easier to code with.

Database also works, however if the test system will be used for “real” then the internet on the test device might be turned off, which will result in no communication with the database

//Galin